# What are the main tools/frameworks used nowadays in Java?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee

I am a .NET / C++ programmer switching to Java. I had previous exposure to Java 10+ years ago in university.

What would be the typical things to be learned in order to be able to program web applications in Java?

I can think of:
JSP/Servlets
Eclipse
EJB

What else do people use these days?

The idea would be to be able to land on a Java project and make myself useful

Answer (score 9):

[Hibernate](https://www.hibernate.org/) and [Spring](http://www.springsource.org/)

Comment: Personally, I'd avoid Hibernate unless you *know* you need it for some reason.  It's a monster dependency, full of magic, and difficult to control if perf is a concern.  I've spent considerable time banging my head against it and removing it from code where it shouldn't have been used.  Stick with vanilla JDBC; at least you'll know what your code is doing.

Comment: Then I am afraid you will need hibernate since that is what projects use nowadays. IF it is a good framework or not was not the question here.

Comment: Hibernate is used on a lot of Java web applications whether or not it is actually used the way it should be used.  I agree with overthink's comment - Hibernate can cause a lot of issues, more than if you just used JDBC directly.  However, I'd like to add that if you're using Spring, you *shouldn't* be using JDBC directly - Spring's JDBCTemplate (or advanced subclasses if using Java 5+) should be used instead, as it handles exceptions in a much more meaningful way.

Answer (score 4):

Tools department:
[Eclipse](http://www.eclipse.org/) and [Netbeans](http://www.netbeans.org/)

(For web-centric Java development, see the Eclipse based [Aptana IDE](http://www.aptana.com/))

Comment: ...or, if you want something better (and are willing to pay for it), IntelliJ IDEA ;-)

Comment: people complain all the time about Eclipse, but it's still a strong reference.

If you want to hack some Google Android or Blackberry Apps, SDKs are available for the Eclipse platform.

Answer (score 4):

I migrate between a lot of clients who use Java heavily. Here's what I see people use:

a) a lot:

- JDBC
- Servlets
- Ant
- Log4J
- Eclipse/Intellij

b) quite often:

- JSP
- Spring
- Maven
- Web Services
- the Apache Commons libraries

c) barely ever:

- EJBs (not since 2002 or so!).

I've not come across Hibernate or other ORMs. I'm not sure why, I confess, since it seems popular in the context of SO.

Comment: +1, seems quite realistic to me. (Although personally I haven't used  JDBC directly for ages; database access is hidden behind Hibernate.)

Comment: Maybe you should start recommending Hibernate to your clients. I can't even imagine writing a J2EE app without it these days.

Comment: The above reflects what I find, not what I recommend.

Answer (score 2):

If you are focusing on web applications specifically, it's important to know and understand many topics that are independent of Java:

- JavaScript
- SQL
- CSS
- XML (XPath in particular)
- HTML
- HTTP

You need to get a grasp of these concepts before learning Java frameworks that may or may not simplify the creation of code dealing with them.

As far as Java-specific libraries and frameworks go, these are essential:

- Servlets and JSPs
- JDBC
- Ant
- [Apache Commons](http://commons.apache.org/) -- for the love of all that's good, don't re-invent common libraries!

These are nice to have but are too narrow to focus on before learning everything above:

- Spring
- Hibernate
- Maven
- JSF

Comment: +1 for XPath. I've seen many a buggy 'indexOf' search in an XML string, where an xpath would have been much cleaner!

Answer (score -1):

Grails is also a Java platform web application framework, although it's coded in the Groovy language rather than Java, which is more like Python or Ruby and is dynamically typed.

Answer (score -1):

It is based on the Project and Company, i am writing few tools/framworks which i came across

**IDE :**

- Eclipse
- Jboss developer
- Ibm Rad
- Spring tool suit(sts)

**Repository**

- Svn
- Smartsvn
- tourtoise
- Git

**Built Tools**
 - Ant
 - Maven

**Presentation**
 -Html, javascript, jquery, ajax
 -Html with jsp
 -Html with Struts tags
 -Html with Spring tag liabaries

**Controller**
 -Servlets
 -Struts
 -Spring

**Business**
 -Ejb
 -Spring

**Database**
  -Jdbc
  -Spring

**Other**
 - WebService - Soap , Rest
 - Putty
 - FileZilla
 - log$j
 - Mokitio
 - Junit